# electron: Failed to load URL: app://-/ with error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop-application

I started building a desktop app using Electron Js that enable users to upload a folder that contains client side web app (either a native one with html, css, js files or other based on a framworke like Vue.js) and serve its content like what the browser do, in a new window after that the user click for ex on preview button. I used for that purpose a library called 'electron-serve', but each time I start the app and click the preview button nothing is shown (I expect to get a new window that show the served web app), and the following error is shown in the console of my vscode:

> (node:12068) electron: Failed to load URL: app://-/ with error:
> ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (Use electron --trace-warnings ... to show where
> the warning was created) (node:12068)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (-6)
> loading 'app://-/' at rejectAndCleanup
> (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:7510) at
> EventEmitter.failListener (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:165:7723)
> at EventEmitter.emit (node:events:527:28) (node:12068)
> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
> error originated either by throwing inside of an async function
> without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled
> with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise
> rejection, use the CLI flag --unhandled-rejections=strict (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).

And here is a minimal reproducible example of my project

main.js :

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, BrowserView, ipcMain, protocol } = require("electron");
const serve = require('electron-serve');
const path = require("path");
const url = require('url');
const isDiv = process.eventNames.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const isMac = process.platform === "darwin";
let loadURL = serve({ directory : path.join(__dirname, "./compressedFolder") });

let mainWindow;
// let view;

// create main window
function createMainWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    icon: path.join(__dirname, "src/img/greenieweb.icns"),
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    minHeight: 600,
    minWidth: 1000,
    webPreferences: {
      title: "GreenieWeb",
      preload: path.join(__dirname, "/src/preload/preload.js"),
      devTools: true /*Disables Devtools*/,
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  });

  // open dev tools if in dev env
  if (isDiv) {
    mainWindow.webContents.openDevTools();
  }

  ipcMain.on('app-topreview-loaded', async (event) => {
    const previewWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      parent: mainWindow,
      show: false,
      width: 1200,
      height: 800,
      minHeight: 600,
      minWidth: 1000,
      webPreferences: {
        title: "Preview",
      },
    })
    await loadURL(previewWindow);
    previewWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
        previewWindow.show()
      })
  })
  // load main html file
  mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, "./index.html"));
}

// App is ready
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  // create the main window
  createMainWindow();

  // Disable menu
  // Menu.setApplicationMenu(null);

  // remove mainwindow from memory on close
  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });

  // create window if none is created when app is active
  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createMainWindow();
    }
  });
});
```

renderer.js :

```
let previewBtn = document.getElementById("preview-btn");


const fs = versions.fs;


let gFRWRPCounter = 0;
let isEmptyDir = true


previewBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(!isEmptyDir){
        removeFolderFromDir()
    }
    addFolderToThePlace()
    
    window.electronAPI.showWebApp()
})

function removeFolderFromDir(){
    fs.rmSync('./compressedFolder', { recursive: true, force: true });
    fs.mkdir("./compressedFolder", (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log("Something went wrong")
        }
    })
    isEmptyDir = true;
    gFRWRPCounter = 0;
}

async function addFolderToThePlace(){
    if(directoryHandle===undefined){
        new Notification(emptyFolderNOTIFICATION_TITLE, {
            body: emptyFolderNOTIFICATION_BODY,
        }).show();
        return;
    }
    for await (const file of getFilesRecursivelyWithRP("", directoryHandle)) {
        const content = await file.text()
        await fs.mkdir(
            "./compressedFolder" + file.relativePath,
            { recursive: true },
            (err) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    fs.writeFileSync(
                        "./compressedFolder" + file.relativePath + "/" + file.name,
                        content
                    );
                }
            }
        );
    }
    isEmptyDir = false
}


async function* getFilesRecursivelyWithRP(fPath, entry) {
    if (entry.kind === "file") {
        const file = await entry.getFile();
        if (file !== null) {
            file.relativePath = fPath;
            yield file;
        }
    } else if (entry.kind === "directory") {
        let nFPath = "";
        if(gFRWRPCounter>0){
            nFPath = fPath + "/" + entry.name;
        }else{
            nFPath = fPath
            gFRWRPCounter++;
        }
        for await (const handle of entry.values()) {
            yield* getFilesRecursivelyWithRP(nFPath, handle);
        }
    }
}
```

preload.js :

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");
const fs = require('fs')

// this is just an example
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("versions", {
  fs: fs,
});

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  showWebApp: () => ipcRenderer.send('app-topreview-loaded')
})
```

Help please.